# jQuery Tools overlay & validator combined...unable to reach validator api

Tags: jquery, api, overlay, validation

I've combined 2 jQuery Tools: overlay and validator.
Both work great separately. But when i combine them... (loading the contactform in an overlay with an external load) i'm unable to reach the validator api (or instance) the validator partially works. but im unable to reach the onSucces event preventing the form to submit before all is validated.

Please help me.

this is the validator loading script:

```
$("#frm_contact").validator({api:true}).submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                api = $("frm_contact").data("validator");
                // use API to assign an event listener
                api.onSuccess(function(e, els) {
                alert("prima");
                pageTracker._trackPageview('/ContactSubmit');
                         $.ajax({
                              type:'POST', 
                              url: 'process.php', 
                              data:form.serialize(), 
                              cache: false,
                              beforeSend: function(){
                                $('.contentWrap').html("<br /><br /><br /><h3 class=\"contact\">Processing your request...</h3>").fadeIn('slow');
                              }, 
                              error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown) { 
                                //alert(errorThrown+'\n'+status+'\n'+xhr.statusText); 
                              },
                              success: function(response) {
                                $('.contentWrap').html(response).fadeIn('slow', function(){
                                    $('.contentWrap').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow', function(){   
                                        overlayElem.overlay().close();
                                    });
                                });
                              },
                         });

                return false;               
                });          
            });

            $.tools.validator.localize("en", {'[required]'    : '* Required'});
```

which is loaded inside the overlay-element making this the whole code:

```
$(function(){   
    $("#ctactbtn").live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default link action
    e.stopPropagation();

    overlayElem = $(this); 
    $(this).overlay({
        mask: 'silver',
        api: true,
        load: true,
        onBeforeLoad: function() {
             pageTracker._trackPageview('/contact');

            // grab wrapper element inside content
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
            $(".contentWrap").fadeIn();
            // load the page specified in the trigger
            wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        },
        onLoad: function() {
            lastCountry = "";
            $('#countries').change(function () { 
                var option = $("#"+$(this).val()).attr('option');
                if(lastCountry != null){
                    $(lastCountry).fadeOut(500, function() {if(option == "CC"){ $(".contentWrap").animate({height: '400'},500);$(".cWbg").animate({height: '400'},500);}});
                }
                if(option == "CC_Details" | "Details" ){
                    huidig = $("#"+$(this).val());
                    $(".cWbg").animate({height: '460'},500);
                    $(".contentWrap").animate({height: '460'}, 500, function(){ huidig.fadeIn(); });
                }
                if(option == "CC_Details" | "CC" ){
                    $('#CC').val($("#"+$(this).val()).attr('email'));
                } else {
                    $('#CC').val("");
                        if(lastCountry != null){
                            $(lastCountry).fadeOut(500, function() {$(".contentWrap").animate({height: '400'},500);$(".cWbg").animate({height: '400'},500);});
                        }
                }
                lastCountry = "#"+$(this).val(); 
            }).change();


            $("#frm_contact").validator({api:true}).submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                api = $("frm_contact").data("validator");
                // use API to assign an event listener
                api.onSuccess(function(e, els) {
                alert("prima");
                pageTracker._trackPageview('/ContactSubmit');
                         $.ajax({
                              type:'POST', 
                              url: 'process.php', 
                              data:form.serialize(), 
                              cache: false,
                              beforeSend: function(){
                                $('.contentWrap').html("<br /><br /><br /><h3 class=\"contact\">Processing your request...</h3>").fadeIn('slow');
                              }, 
                              error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown) { 
                                //alert(errorThrown+'\n'+status+'\n'+xhr.statusText); 
                              },
                              success: function(response) {
                                $('.contentWrap').html(response).fadeIn('slow', function(){
                                    $('.contentWrap').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow', function(){   
                                        overlayElem.overlay().close();
                                    });
                                });
                              },
                         });

                return false;               
                });          
            });

            $.tools.validator.localize("en", {'[required]'    : '* Required'}); 


        },
        onBeforeClose: function(){
            $("#frm_contact").data("validator").reset();
            $('.error').hide(); $('.error').empty();
        }
    });
});



});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar recently. It seems like there is dependent code that is shared between the following 3 libraries:

- dateinput/dateinput.js
- rangeinput/rangeinput.js
- validator/validator.js

I am only using the validator in my project, but to make it work properly I had to include references to all 3 related libraries when generating the JS file from the JQuery UI site.